# Makefile vpath %.o not finding obj files

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm using the following vpath to attempt locating my $(OBJ) files:

```
vpath %.o ./lib/obj
```

And my target is setup as such:

```
# Link target
link:
    @echo "\nLinking files"
    $(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o main.elf $(OBJS)
```

When looking at the output, I get (for all the *.o files):

```
...error: misc.o: No such file or directory
```

My project structure looks as follows:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── inc
│   └── main.h
├── lib
│   ├── inc
│   │   ├── cmsis
│   │   │   ├── arm_common_tables.h
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── peripherals
│   │   │   ├── misc.h
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── stm32f4xx
│   │       ├── stm32f4xx.h
│   │       ├── ...
│   ├── obj
│   │   ├── misc.o
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── peripherals
│   │   │   ├── misc.c
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── system_stm32f4xx.c
│   └── startup_stm32f4xx.s
├── src
│   └── main.c
└── stm32f4.ld
```

Why are my .o files not being found?

Full output for reference:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -T"stm32f3.ld" -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,"main.map"
>   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -g3 -gdwarf-2 -L"./" -o main.elf misc.o stm32f4xx_adc.o stm32f4xx_can.o stm32f4xx_crc.o stm32f4xx_cryp.o
>   stm32f4xx_cryp_aes.o stm32f4xx_cryp_des.o stm32f4xx_cryp_tdes.o
>   stm32f4xx_dac.o stm32f4xx_dbgmcu.o stm32f4xx_dcmi.o stm32f4xx_dma.o
>   stm32f4xx_exti.o stm32f4xx_flash.o stm32f4xx_fsmc.o stm32f4xx_gpio.o
>   stm32f4xx_hash.o stm32f4xx_hash_md5.o stm32f4xx_hash_sha1.o
>   stm32f4xx_i2c.o stm32f4xx_iwdg.o stm32f4xx_pwr.o stm32f4xx_rcc.o
>   stm32f4xx_rng.o stm32f4xx_rtc.o stm32f4xx_sdio.o stm32f4xx_spi.o
>   stm32f4xx_syscfg.o stm32f4xx_tim.o stm32f4xx_usart.o stm32f4xx_wwdg.o
>   system_stm32f4xx.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following to my Makefile:

```
OBJS = $(LIB_SRC:.c=.o)
OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix lib/out/,$(notdir $(LIB_SRC:.c=.o)))
```

and updated the target:

```
link:
    @echo "\nLinking files"
    $(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o main.elf $(OBJ_FILES)
```

The linker is now finding the .o files correctly.

Comment: Yes, that would be the tedious way of doing it by hand.  As Chris pointed out, you want to make the object files proper dependencies of the link rule (so that they are rebuilt when necessary; this is most of the point of using make!).  At that point, you might as well do it properly and do this via `vpath`/`$+`, taking advantage of the prerequisites that you have anyway.

Answer (score 5):

`$(OBJS)` is just a variable, and gets expanded as text.  When it appears in the text of the command in your `link` rule, it is simply expanded as text.

`vpath` searches are applied to **prerequisites**, so you will have to arrange for your `$(OBJS)` to appear as prerequisites to your link rule and for the rule's commands to [use those prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes_002fSearch.html) (via automatic variables, rather than just using `$(OBJS)` directly).

So your rule needs to look more like

```
# Link target
link: main.elf

main.elf: $(OBJS)
    @echo "\nLinking files"
    $(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o $@ $+
```

(I have also taken the liberty of writing out the file generated (*main.elf*) as the non-phony target of an intermediate rule.  Making these things explicit to Make is generally a good idea.)

Comment: I still get the same output as with my question, it doesn't resolve for example misc.o to ./lib/out/misc.o

Comment: @josef: Presumably you neglected to change the `$(CC) ...` line to use the automatic variable (`$+` or `$^`) containing the resolved prerequisite names.  As noted in [the documentation I pointed you at](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes_002fSearch.html), this is critical.

Answer (score 5):

Although the other answers are correct in the details of what they say, there is a larger point here: it is not possible to use VPATH/vpath reliably to find *derived* files, like .o files that you build from your makefile.  VPATH/vpath is *only* useful for finding *source* files, such as .c files.

You should read http://make.mad-scientist.net/vpath.html

Answer (score 3):

`vpath` just tells make where to find the files, not the compiler/linker.  You have to get make to tell the compiler/linker where it found them.  The easiest way is to make them proper dependencies (so they get rebuilt before linking) and then use `$^`:

```
# Link target
link: $(OBJS)
        @echo "\nLinking files"
        $(CC) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o main.elf $^
```

Comment: I still get the same output as with my question, it doesn't resolve for example misc.o to ./lib/out/misc.o